# Difficulty trying to use the SPK file ast343de430.bsp

Tags: orbital-mechanics, software, jpl-horizons, ephemeris

I'm looking for a NAIF SPK file (these typically end in `.bsp`) for a bunch of asteroids in the J2000 reference frame. I found `ast343de430.bsp` at `ftp://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/eph/small_bodies/asteroids_de430/ast343de430.bsp`. They seem to be referenced to J2000 and they they have `10` (sun) as their center reference, but when I go to plot them they look wonky.

When I overlay their traces on `de430.bsp` I get epicyclic looking traces for each individual body and the cloud of points seem to form the characteristic asteroid belt shape but offset by 2-3AU.

I'm using a basic SPK reader I've developed myself. The code is [here](https://github.com/kghose/groho/tree/master/src/orrery) (MIT licensed, as the question arose below). This reader is fine with the publicly released large body and satellite files (https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/generic_kernels/spk/planets/, https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/generic_kernels/spk/satellites/)

Has anyone used this file and did they have any issues with it? Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh Don't know about asteroid files specifically, but I can load up all the publicly released large body files + pluto (https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/generic_kernels/spk/planets/, https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/generic_kernels/spk/satellites/) with no issues. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, this is slightly off topic, but is your SPK reader open source by any chance? I'm currently trying to read an SPK / DAF reader myself, and having a bit of a hard time.

Comment: @ChrisR MIT licensed here: https://github.com/kghose/groho . The reader bits are here: https://github.com/kghose/groho/tree/master/src/orrery

Comment: @uhoh , I found Brandon Rhodes' [jplephem](https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/python-jplephem) quite nice to use.

Comment: I would suggest using CSPICE (https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/) to read SPICE kernel (SPK) files. If not, Brandon Rhodes' skyfield (https://github.com/skyfielders/python-skyfield) which is more recent than pyephem. I explain the SPICE format here: https://github.com/skyfielders/python-skyfield/issues/19 and have written a SPICE file reader for Mathematica (but written in Perl) at https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/ASTRO/bc-xsp2math.pl (other files in that directory may also be useful). http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13488/ may also be useful.

Comment: @barrycarter do you have a goto piece of software you use to cross check/sanity check things? It's a hobby project and one of the things I enjoy doing (kind of ..) is to do it all myself. So if my reader is missing something I need, I like to add it myself. In this case I'd like to be sure it's me that's wonky rather than the file. Thanks!

Comment: @KaushikGhose I'd use CSPICE (and HORIZONS) as my check. If they disagree with your results, it's probably your code that's erring, not theirs.

Comment: Folks - there was a bug in my program and I was able to proceed once I could use `jplephem` to plot the file data. Thanks for all your help! I can write this up as an answer basically just pointing out the non-self contained nature of the file (it references everything to `10` but does not contain `10` itself) and recommending `jplephem` as a way of cross-checking computations. I just needed all you guys camaraderie to remember  `jplephem`! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `ast343de430.bsp` file looks to be fine. There is only one thing of note - all bodies in this file are referenced to the sun (`10`) but the ephemeris of the sun is not included. (The reason is given [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/timeephem/timeephem-devel/message/33103556/) - the author of this file considers the position of the Sun to be better defined than the SSB). For this reason an additional `.bsp` file which contains the SSB should be used, unless you are happy using the Sun as origin of the co-ordinate system.

Comment: I think you can definitely accept this one though ;-)